# SBT reference error after openapi code generation

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, openapi-generator

I have a Scala / SBT multi module project where one module uses generated code from an OpenAPI specification. The module also has source code in src/main/scala.

What I need to do is this:

- reference company templates as dependency
- unpack company templates to a directory inside target
- generate openapi code using said templates
- compile generated and non-generated code together as a Play application

After long debugging, I did get SBT to do all of that in the right order on `sbt compile`. However, while the compiling succeeds, I do get an error afterwards:

```
[error] (rest / Compile / compile) sbt.internal.util.Init$RuntimeUndefined: References to undefined settings at runtime.
[error] ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/path/to/my/project/,rest)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),compile) referenced from setting(ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/path/to/my/project/,rest)), Select(ConfigKey(compile)), Zero, Zero),compile)) at LinePosition(/path/to/my/project/build.sbt,33)
```

What can I do about that error?

Here's my build.sbt:

```
lazy val `rest` = Project(id = "rest", base = file("."))
  .enablePlugins(OpenApiGeneratorPlugin, PlayScala, UnpackPlugin)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.mycompany" % "mycompany-templates" % "0.0.3"
      // other dependencies omitted
    ),
    dependencyFilter := { (file: File) => file.getName.startsWith("mycompany-templates") },
    dependenciesJarDirectory := (ThisProject / target).value,
    openApiInputSpec := ((ThisProject / baseDirectory).value / "../api/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml").absolutePath,
    openApiConfigFile := (baseDirectory.value / "codegen-config.yaml").absolutePath,
    openApiGeneratorName := "scala-play-server",
    openApiOutputDir := ((ThisProject / baseDirectory).value / "target" / "gen-src" / "openapi").absolutePath,
    openApiTemplateDir := ((ThisProject / baseDirectory).value / "target" / "templates" / "domino-play-server").absolutePath,
    Compile / sourceGenerators += Def.task { 
      val generatedFiles = openApiGenerate.value
      generatedFiles.filter(f => f.getName.endsWith(".scala"))
    }.taskValue,

    // this is the line in the error message:
    Compile / compile := Def.sequential(unpackJars, openApiGenerate, Compile / compile).value,

    Compile / managedSourceDirectories += (ThisProject / target).value / "gen-src" / "openapi" / "app",
    Compile / managedResourceDirectories += (ThisProject / target).value / "gen-src" / "openapi" / "conf",
    Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += (ThisProject / baseDirectory).value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The `Compile / compile` definition needs to look like this:

```
Compile / compile := 
    ((Compile / compile) dependsOn Def.sequential(unpackJars, openApiGenerate)).value
```